# Google Charts: Is there a way to re-render the chart when the screen changes sizes? (javascript only please)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to make a javascript google chart that renders and when I test responsiveness the chart does not move until I refresh the screen and the chart re-renders. Where I see this becoming a problem is  turning an Ipad or phone to portrait or resizing of a window  and the chart no longer being centered. Is there a way to re-render the Charts on the screen size changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, just need to re-draw when the the `'resize'` event occurs,
something like...

```
window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);

function drawChart() {
  chart.draw();
}
```

Comment: hope this helps, if you want to share some code, i can provide a more detailed answer...